# Verify computation result on chain

Tags: signature, hash, proof

I would like to know if there is a way to verify the correctness of an input (a number) on-chain.

This is my current design: The `deposit` function on `contractA` takes an input called `computeResult`. However, calling `computeResult` on-chain is expensive due to the large loop involved. To save on gas costs, we decided to compute the result off-chain via an on-chain call to the `computeResult` function. A bot then computes the result through an RPC call and pushes it on-chain. However, this makes the `deposit` function a two-step process instead of an atomic one.

I am trying to figure out a solution to make this process atomic. I am wondering if a `contractB` with the `computeResult` function would help. When a user calls `deposit`, my front-end could also call `computeResult` and provide a signature encoding the result, along with elements proving that the result is from the `contractB` and cannot be imitated.

Do you have any ideas on how to implement this?

Thank you.